# float: left; Not working in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-float

(I'm looking at [this site](http://yogadetoxretreat.co.uk/) in IE 8.) As you can see the content floats center knocking the sidebar below it. It works perfectly in Chrome. I can't think why the float:left; command isn't working in IE.

```
#content {
margin: 5px 0 5px 5px;
font: 1.2em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
width:65%;
float:left;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Tara

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `overflow: hidden` to your `ul#list-nav` then that will prevent the floating navigation messing up the rest of the document.

As for why the navigation is displaying strangely, it's because you're specifying your widths and layout badly. What you should be using is this:

```
ul#list-nav {
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul#list-nav li {
    width: 16.66%;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul#list-nav li a{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 1px;text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background: #754C78;
    color: #EEE;
    text-align: center;
}
```

That way, the width of each element is exactly `16.66%`, rather than `16.62% + 1px`

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestions also worked great and I'm going to stick with this method because it's flexible when zoomed :)

Answer (score 3):

what i currently see in IE8 is:
[image]

the problem is that menu links are too wide in IE. You've set the `width` to 16.62% to each anchor in the menu and that's too wide for IE. Since the width of your content is fixed I suggest you set fixed width in pixels (132px) for these links so they fit on one line and look consistent across browsers, also removing `li` style setting `margin: 0.5em 2em` to fix positioning problem in IE.

After my fix I see this:
[image]

Comment: @Tara Note that there is still that extra letter `s` in your markup ( also is shown in both of these screenshots )

Comment: @lollero Thanks for pointing that out. I've found the S and deleted it now. Sorry I re-picked Eric as the best answer because his method allows flexibility while zooming.

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like theres nothing really wrong with the content.

In ie6-ie9 the menu seems to be failing in some way.

and also the menu goes in two rows which pushes everything down. I'm not sure if that is all due to the `s` letter or not at this point..

**Note** that the extra letter `s` seems to be somewhere between `#menu` and `#content` `.containers`.

Edit2: the problem is clearly the `menu a` width which is too much and the menu goes into two rows.

The way menu is often done is that the `ul`or outer div holds the color and then the `menu li` are either centered within that or just plain floated to the left. this way you get the full height feel without the tourbles of the menu braking like this ( though if you do it without ignoring the width.. it is possible with too many menu items and so on. )

Comment: `clear: both` on the `#menu` doesn't help. That will make the menu clear floats that come before it, not floats that come inside it. To clear contained floats, use `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Yes, i did not notice that each element has been wrapped separately like they are. Though the best way of doing this in my opinion would be to wrap everything in `#wrap`and put `margin 0 auto;` to  that and remove `margin: o auto;` from `.container` and put `float: left; clear: both;` to the `.container`

Comment: @lollero I don't understand... what would that achieve? The clear:left; seemed to sort out the floating of the content and sidebar. (Also note that the 'content' is inside the 'container'.)

Comment: Well, to put it shortly. Its more bulletproof. I'm afraid that how you have done it might not work so well in some versions of IE. `clear` works against `floated` elements _that are in its right or left_ and this means that what you should `clear` is in fact `.container` but they cant be cleared as they are not floated. You cant just throw in `float: left;` to `.container` cause that would make `margin: 0 auto;` useless in those elements. Therefore outer wrap helps you a lot. http://jsfiddle.net/Lxe5Q/ - im not sure if this will help but i hope it does. Check the comments in the code.

Comment: Note that i said _might not work_ because technically what your code is doing should push the elements vertically in order as they are. I never trust IE... never.. Even as im writing this i'm keeping my eye on IE... theres no guessing what it will do next, but when it does.. ill be ready.

Answer (score 1):

add clear:both; on menu container.

note: is broken in Firefox to